How can I do Tailscale authentication with Paramiko?
I'm writing a script that uses the Tailscale API to get a list of devices, then uses Paramiko to connect via SSH and query some data on the device. This worked fine yesterday, but today all the connections failed. I realised that behind the scenes, the SSH is failing because it's being managed by Tailscale and needs reauthentication:
ssh root@MyDevice
# Tailscale SSH requires an additional check.
# To authenticate, visit: https://login.tailscale.com/a/XXXXXX

But how can I detect and resolve this with Paramiko? My current code is pretty basic, but I was able to add logging:
import requests
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import paramiko
import logging

url = "https://api.tailscale.com/api/v2/tailnet/-/devices"

# https://tailscale.com/kb/1085/auth-keys#generate-an-auth-key
headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer GENERATED AUTH KEY"}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

# print(response.json())
data = response.json()
devices = data['devices']

current = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(minutes = 1)

class OnlyTailscaleFilter(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if 'Auth banner' in record.getMessage():
            if "b'" in record.getMessage():
                temp_array = record.getMessage().split("'")
                temp = temp_array[1].replace('\\n', '\n')
                temp = temp.replace('\\r', '\r')
                print(temp)
                return False
            return True
        return False

logging.basicConfig()
logger = logging.getLogger("paramiko.transport")
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addFilter(OnlyTailscaleFilter())

for device in devices:
    if 'lastSeen' in device:
        last_seen = datetime.strptime(device['lastSeen'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
        if last_seen > current:
            hostname = ''
            uptime_seconds = ''
                    
            if 'hostname' in device:
                hostname = device['hostname']

            ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
            ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
            try:
                ssh.connect(device['addresses'][0], username='root')
            except paramiko.AuthenticationException as ex:
                print('{}, An authentication exception occurred: {}'.format(hostname, ex))
            else:
                ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command('cat /proc/uptime')
                if ssh_stdout.channel.recv_exit_status() == 0:
                    temp = ssh_stdout.readlines()
                    if temp:
                        temp = temp[0].strip('\n').strip('\"')
                        uptime_seconds = temp.split()[0]

                print(hostname, ',', uptime_seconds)
                ssh.close()

When I run it, I can see this in the log:
# Tailscale SSH requires an additional check.
# To authenticate, visit: https://login.tailscale.com/a/XXXXX\n'

and I have 60 seconds to authenticate before it throws an exception. If I authenticate I see:
# Authentication checked with Tailscale SSH.
# Time since last authentication: 0s

and the script continues.
But how can I get this message and URL properly?

Also raised as https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/2425
